# How to use ever?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm learning English and I'm wondering some words of usage, like how to use 'ever' (For example: **You're the best ever.**)

What does the *ever* mean in that sentence?

Comment: *The best ever = The one never seen before.*

Comment: [The definition you're looking for is "at any time".](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ever)  When someone says "It's the best ever", you could think of it as "It's the best that there has ever been."

Answer (score 1):

> **"You're the best ever"**

is idiomatic and colloquial, frequently tossed off as a compliment in passing. It usually does **not** take the literal meaning of "there has never been a person better than you." It is a nice thing to say to someone, nothing more.

For instance, if someone put some time into answering a question for you, you could reply by saying, "You're the best!" or "You're the best ever." But that doesn't mean someone gave you the best answer you have ever read. It is more like saying, "Thank you! I appreciate it."